# What determines the entries in the Outlook address book?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

Are there published standards for who appears in the Outlook global address book in a hybrid Office 365/Exchange environment? Like disabled users, users with only a phone number, contacts in a non-synced OU, etc.

Note that we can manually change the settings in a mailbox to hide the user from address lists but a better solution would be to understand who appears and manage them holistically.

Comment: Users/mailboxes with the msExchHideFromAddressLists set to FALSE.

Comment: So if a user has nothing in that value, they will not show up in the address list? I've searched and found users with nothing there and they are in the list.

Comment: mailbox-enabled and mail-enabled objects appear in the GAL. What do you mean you want to manage them holistically? What does that mean, exactly?

Comment: @Keith If it's either FALSE or missing/blank, the address will be visible in the GAL.

Comment: By holistically, I mean I'd like to set up an OU we can move all disabled users to and that will automatically remove them from the address book as well as allow other systems to know they are not valid users. Or switch a property in AD to do the same, etc.

Comment: To clarify - the "hide from address book" property does not necessarily mean they have left the company so using only that property to identify terminated users in other situations is not valid. I'd like a single change to mark a user terminated and that change works in all systems to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in GAL that's automatically created by Exchange includes every mail-enabled object in the Active Directory forest. Includes all mail-enabled recipient objects in the organization (users, contacts, groups, dynamic distribution groups, and public folders.

In hybrid deployment, on-premise users will see all recipients in GAL, cloud users will see the synced recipients.

Yes, only key setting is “hide from address list”.

Comment: So if a user leaves the company and their mailbox is on legal hold, they will always appear in the address book unless you hide them intentionally? Is that the intended functionality? For example, if they are not on legal hold, the mailbox is deleted 30 days after they are no longer licensed so clearly the intention is to delete users who have left the company within 30 days. From an address book perspective, the same should hold true if they are on legal hold, right?